# connecting Android APP to FTP server

Tags: java, android, ftp, filezilla

I'm having a problem on connecting an android app to a filezilla ftp server. The server is functional but still i'm getting this output on LogCat:

```
05-30 19:49:43.872: D/$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$(1693): $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ERROR 1
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1002)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:175)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:196)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:289)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at General.FTPHandle.Connect(FTPHandle.java:40)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at General.FTPHandle.doInBackground(FTPHandle.java:30)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at General.FTPHandle.doInBackground(FTPHandle.java:1)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
05-30 19:50:04.913: W/System.err(1693): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
05-30 19:50:04.933: W/System.err(1693): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
05-30 19:50:04.933: W/System.err(1693): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

the code is the following one:

```
public class FTPHandle extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    public FTPClient client = null;
    public FileInputStream fis = null;
    private File root;
    private File dir;

    public FTPHandle()
    {
        client = new FTPClient();
        fis = null; 
        root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath()+ "/TrackingData"); //creates directory
        execute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        Connect();
        return null;
    }

    public int Connect()
    {
        int status = 0;

        try {
            Log.d("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$","$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ERROR 1");
            client.connect("192.168.1.64");
            Log.d("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$","$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ERROR 2");

            // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
            fis = new FileInputStream(dir);
            // Store file to server
            client.storeFile(dir.getName(), fis);
            client.logout();

            status = 1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            status = 0;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

Ps: The server is functional. I've tested it ;)

Kind Regards

Comment: You definitely need to use `192.168.1.64`, not `ftp://192.168.1.64`. What error do you get, when you use just `192.168.1.64`?

Comment: A timeout error.. should i specify the port?

Comment: Please include a complete exception dump into your question (you can remove the dump for the `ftp://...` scenario and that's useless). You should not need to specify the port, if it is a default 21.

Comment: Martin Prikryl the question was now updated ;).

Comment: Ok, were you able to connect using any other Android FTP client? I guess that it would not work either. In that case this question should better go to [su] or [sf].

Comment: Ahh.. damn the problem was in bad configuration of Windows firewall. Also, for the record, if we want the server to be accessed from outside, the router must be configured to allow traffic on port 20 and 21.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post your resolution as an answer and accept it.